# EF Async Methods - best practices / improvements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, task

Sorry for a subjective question like this:

I current have a sequential loading method which was extremely slow, I have converted this into a async method:

```
    public async void LoadData(int releaseId, int projectId, bool uiThread)
```

Within this method I start up an Await task (and set the ConfigureAwait to be false) as it does not need to capture and resume from this context.

```
     await Task.Run(() =>
     { 
         //make several DB calls as below 

     }).ConfigureAwait(False);
```

Within this task I make several async calls to EF / the database, each call looks something like this:

```
    public async virtual Task<List<X>> FindXAsync()
    {
        var q = from c in context.X
                select c;
        return await q.ToListAsync();
    }
```

But in the task I am awaiting the response by using result see below:

```
    X = sm.FindXAsync().Result;
```

From my limited knowledge of using asynchronous programming with EF would each call run sequentially from inside the task?

Will the current set up return multiple return sets concurrently or would I have to create multiple tasks and await them separatly.

Again sorry for the vague question but i'm sure you guys are a lot more experienced on this topic than me ^^

---

Edit: I release there wasn't really a proper question in there, I guess what I am wondering is would x,y and z return concurrently or sequentially from within the task.

```
     await Task.Run(() =>
     {
          x = sm.FindXAsync().Result;

          y = new ObservableCollection<Y>(sm.FindYAsync().Result);

          z = new ObservableCollection<Z>(sm.FindZAsync().Result);
     }).ConfigureAwait(False)
```

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: [Avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: "would each call run sequentially from inside the task?" Inside the task (if you do not run synchronously deliberately), yes if you await them. You don't need to run them on a different thread using a `Task.Run`, an asyc method itself is enough.

Comment: @Transcendent so an async methods inside the task will run on their own thread, despite requiring the result in the task ?

Comment: Actually the the Task you have written in your code, does not accept any async functionality. So the code itself has some problem. But why do you wanna use a Task, please elaborate more.

Comment: For speed benefits mostly, ideally shifting parts of the load onto their own long running tasks/threads. I started by added a single task to encompass several async DB calls but i guess that's not doing what i expected

Comment: @mason So I should change the void to a Task due to the differences between how async handles exceptions (amongst other things) - thanks :)

Comment: @Chris: The entity framework does not provide you with any performance over the Db, this is obvious because it is an ORM. If you are really after performance, you have to forget about EF. If you can tolerate all those delays EF causes, due to what it does in the background, again using a thread would not optimize it. In fact, EF has its own threading mechanism, you can see this by trying to send massive requests to the db and at the same time track the debugging info. If you do, you see that requests are packed in threads.

Comment: @Transcendent it isn't performance over the DB i am particularly worried about, it's over other UI logic, currently the load method would lock the UI for quite some time, which is unacceptable especially because the data it is loading does not need to be immediately accessed if that makes sense. It is my understanding that the DB calls have to be handled asynchronously otherwise they would block the UI thread which *could* also be trying to access data.

Comment: @Chris: Chris, you are right about long running tasks blocking the UI. To clarify, you don't need to use the Task.Run to solve this problem specially when it comes to Entity Framework. You can define Async methods and await them in your events. If you want, I can provide you an example.

Comment: @Transcendent that would be nice, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the will run sequentially when you use the Result property. Also they will run sequentially with the following code: `

```
    x = await sm.FindXAsync().ConfigureAwait(False);

    y = new ObservableCollection<Y>( await sm.FindYAsync().ConfigureAwait(False));

    z = new ObservableCollection<Z>(await sm.FindZAsync().ConfigureAwait(False));
```

Also update

```
 public async void LoadData to return Task ->  `public async Task LoadData`.
```

If you want to run all code in parallel add the taks in an array and then call `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`

Comment: so i would have to create each task as the return of the async manager methods then use Task.WhenAll(tasks) then assign the results to the local variables? - thanks chris

Comment: @Chris, no, just use this: var tasks = new Task[] {sm.FindXAsync(), sm.FindYAsync(), sm.FindZAsync()}; await Task.WhenAll(tasks); x = tasks[0].Result; y = new ObservableCollection<Y>(tasks[1].Result); z = new ObservableCollection<Z>(tasks[2].Result)

Comment: ok, thanks, I assume the await on the return of the FindXAsync method won't affect the running of the other two tasks (find y and find z) - marked as answer thanks for help :)

Comment: with regards to changing the load data to return a Task instead of void, doesn't this mean that the call would have to be awaited - and to use an awaited call the wrapping method needs to be async and so on .. is there any way to avoid this ?

Comment: Ok after implementing the solution suggested the solution I am getting the following error

 "A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe" 

- I assume this is due to the manager method's overlapping contexts but adding an await to each would essentially make them run sequentially right? Which i don't want.

Comment: Yes, so you need to use different context for each call or just don't  use Task.WhenAll

Comment: creating a new context for each call seems very excessive... what are the other options than task.whenall